# Why isn't my object being updated in a For Loop of ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, for-loop, concurrency, instance

I have a quite complex object and am processing various code over it. In it there is a simple list of "Product" objects which I want to add a value to an "Any" field.

The "root" object looks like this (simplified):

```
public class RefundBasics
    {
        public InvoiceDetail Invoice { get; set; }
        // more....
    }
```

`InvoiceDetail` looks like:

```
public class InvoiceDetail
    {
        public SaveSaleRecord.SaveSaleRequest sale { get; set; }
        // more....
    }
```

`SaveSaleRequest` looks like:

```
    public class SaveSaleRequest 
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public ConcurrentQueue<SimpleProduct> Items { get; set; }
        // more....
    }
```

The key object I am having troubles working with is `ConcurrentQueue<SimpleProduct> Items` from the above.

So I have some simple code which is called by:

```
 ReplenishStockOnRefundedItems(Refund, replenish_location, user, apikey, saveChanges);
```

Where `Refund` in the line above is a `RefundBasics` object

This function looks like this (simplified):

```
    internal static void ReplenishStockOnRefundedItems(RefundBasics Refund, string replenish_location, int user, string apikey, bool doit)
    { 
        foreach (SimpleProduct item in Refund.Invoice.sale.Items)
        {
            if (!item.PickPhysicalProduct || item.Quantity <= 0)
                continue;

            string replenish_location_id = "";
            // Some code to determine the value of replenish_location_id 

            // Now store replenish_location_id on this item in the ConcurrentQueue
            item.Any = replenish_location_id;          
        } 
    }
```

**What I am expecting to happen:**

After looping all my items and assigning `replenish_location_id` to the `Any` property of the Item, I can then use it later in my code.

**What is actually happening:**

`Item.Any` is always null (default value), the value is not being assigned to the property.

Any ideas why...? I was thinking it might be because it's a `ConcurrentQueue`, but then, that's back to front? Concurrent objects should be thread safe and more reliable in this kind of loop? That's how understood it and why I am using them here.

I also at one point had a `Linq` `.Where` before my loop instead of the `continue` statement where certain items were not applicable, thinking that might be creating a new set of objects and thus losing the instance, but changing it to the code above made no difference so I am pretty sure it's not an instance problem - unless I am mis-understanding something.

**Edit - following questions:**

`SimpleProduct` is a class and looks like this:

```
public class SimpleProduct
{
    public object Any { get; set; }
    // more properties...
}
```

and yes, I am sure the code is executing past the `if` statement.

Concurrency is not *actually* required for this particular section of code but since `SaveSaleRequest` is a commonly used object within my code, it is required for other things, so the list of items is a concurrent queue for that reason. I *could* convert it to a list before and then back again when running this code, but I don't think I should have to - unless I am miss understanding something?

Comment: Is `SimpleProduct` a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: Are you 100% your code is ever going past that `if` inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: How does  `SimpleProduct` look? Is it a struct by any chance? Are you sure you are looking at the same objects? (use "MakeObjectId" in the debugger to make sure). Are you sure you actually hit the code that updates the "any"-property. ( You might want to reconsider your naming. `items[0].Any` could easily be confused with `items.Any()`)

Comment: Also, Using a concurrent queue in this way may be incorrect, or at least confusing. It should iterate over *some* set of items, but if items are concurrently added/removed they may or may not be included. If items are *not* concurrently added/removed, why are you using a concurrentQueue?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - `SimpleProduct` is a `class`.

The code is definitely going past the `if` I have checked that with a debugger.

For this particular section of code the concurrency is actually not needed, as you suggest @JonasH, however, the `SaveSaleRequest` class is used elsewhere for other things in which concurrency is required. I *could* convert it to a `List` prior to running this code and passing it back on the output, but that seems an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: I will add details of `SimpleProduct`